# Jersey 2: My ApplicationEventListener is being ignored. How do I troubleshoot this?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm using jersey 2.  This is an app I did not set up myself.  I followed the instructions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33271754

But, this isn't doing anything.  I put breakpoints on every method and none of them are ever called whether on startup or on thrown exceptions.  I googled a bit and read that I need to register it in the web.xml with a line like this:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.mypackage.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

But, my ExceptionLogger is already in that package.  Official docs give examples with a ResourceConfig class, but that class doesn't exist in my project (despite the fact that the app runs fine).

I'm not necessarily asking what I'm doing wrong, I want to know how to get some information out of Jersey 2 so that I can troubleshoot what I'm doing wrong.  It doesn't spit out any logs on startup, but the app appears to be running fine when I hit it.  Is there a property I can set to that it will print debugging information about how it's searching for things like `ApplicationEventListener`?

## Update

I figured out how to solve it.  I needed to add this to my web.xml:

```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;com.mypackage.rest.ExceptionLogger</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Can someone explain to me why the `.packages` param wouldn't make the `.classnames` redundant?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin it's not the answer I'm looking for.  I don't know why this works or how to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The listener needs to be annotated with `@Provider`. That's what the package scan is looking for: classes annotated with `@Path` or `@Provider`. It registers all those classes that it finds.

When you use the `classes`, you don't need to use `@Provider` as you're explicitly telling Jersey what classes to register.

Comment: That's good to know, but regardless, how do I get debugging information about this?  Spring boot has a --debug that will tell me tons of useful information, like "found a class named X as a rest endpoint".

Comment: how do you do that?