# ExceptionMapper<Throwable> not called on ForbiddenException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I am using Jersey in Spring Boot. I have a `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` registered via `ResourceConfig.register(MyExceptionMapper.class)` and it is annotated with `@Provider`.

If my code throws a `RuntimeException` `MyExceptionMapper.toResponse()` DOES get called.

However, if my application throws a `javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException`, then my `ExceptionMapper` is not called even though it is a `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>`.

I am assuming that Jersey has a default `ExceptionMapper` that is handing `WebApplicationException` (I assume). How can I customize this?

All I really want to do is add DEBUG logging in the case of any `Throwable` (rest of code works fine for non-WebApplicationException). Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two parts:

First, the reason Jersey is not hitting my `ExceptionMapper` is that it only tries to do so if it does not internally support mapping. The `ServerRuntime.Responder` class attempts to map any `WebApplicationException`. Only if this does not succeed for any reason will the exception be provided to the `ExceptionMapper` (at least that is the behavior I has seen).

Second, there are a couple ways to add logging:

- set the logging level for the `ServerRuntime.Responder`. For me this is too broad as it would log all responses and not just exceptions. This is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484564/905762
- The solution I went with was to add a `ContainerResponseFilter` and get the exception from the `ContainerRequest`. This is somewhat described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680862/905762

  public class ExceptionsLoggingContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
  private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionsLoggingContainerResponseFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, 
      ContainerResponseContext response) {
      Throwable throwable = ((ContainerRequest)response).getMappedThrowable();
      if (throwable != null) {
          LOGGER.info(buildErrorMessage(request), throwable);
      }
  }